# Objective-C issue - expected identifier or '(' before class

Tags: objective-c, compiler-construction

In my header file GuiController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <APPKit/NSTextField.h>
#import "ClientSocket.h"
#import "UploaderThread.h"
#import "DownloaderThread.h"

/**
 * SER 321 Foundations of Distributed Applications
 * see http://pooh.poly.asu.edu/Cst420
 * @author Christopher Sosa (smoothpinkjazz@gmail.com), ASU Polytechnic, Software Engineering
 * @version December 2012
*/

@class AppDelegate; //compiler error
@interface GuiController : NSObject {
    AppDelegate * appDelegate;
    NSSound *sound;
    NSString *port;
    NSString *host;
    ClientSocket *mainSock;
    ClientSocket *songSock;
    UploaderThread *uploader;
    int ident;
    NSTextField *albTB;
    NSComboBox *titCB;
    NSTextField *authTB;

}
- (id) initWithDelegate: (AppDelegate*) theDelegate
               host: (NSString*) hostName
               port: (NSString*) portNum;
- (void) dealloc;

- (void) saveLib;
- (void) restoreLib;
- (void) addMD;
- (void) removeMD;
- (void) refreshMD;
- (void) playMD;
- (void) comboBoxSelectionDidChange: (NSNotification*)notification;
- (void) debug: (NSString*) aMessage;
@end
```

I marked the line that throws an error, even though there doesn't appear to be one.  I am 99% sure the compiler is throwing the error just because it feels like it.  Could you figure out the problem?

Comment: What does your .m file look like?

Comment: Try importing AppDelegate.h ?

Comment: @PeterWarbo The point of using `@class` is to avoid importing the .h file.

Comment: @PeterWarbo: No, that defeats the purpose of `@class`

Comment: Your issue is probably in one the header files being imported.

Comment: Sure I know, but try it as an option to finding out why `@class` is not working.

Comment: "*I am 99% sure the compiler is throwing the error just because it feels like it.*". I am 99% sure you're mistaken. I don't know Objective-C well enough to diagnose the problem, but code errors are much more common than compiler bugs. Compilers don't print error messages just because they "feel like it".

Answer (score 2):

Check your `DownloaderThread.h` file. You probably have an error at the end of it.

Alternatively, `GuiController.h` is being imported from a source file that is not compiled as Obj-C or Obj-C++. Although I'd expect an error much sooner if that was the case (in one of the imported headers).

Comment: I figured it out.  It was missing @end's in UploaderThread.h and DownloaderThread.h.  I'm new to Obj-C, so I'm not quite used to syntax.